# One instance of a pygame sprite is changing a whole groups pos

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

Just making a simple game to practise more than anything where ants start in a nest they leave if they can and find the nearest food that isn't already targeted, so they each have their own path and target. They do this already but whenever I actually move the sprites all the sprites in this group position attributes seem to follow one ants instead of their own path.

```
import pygame
import settings
import random
vec = pygame.math.Vector2


class Ant(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, world):
    self.world = world
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.world.ants, self.world.all_sprites)
    self.image = pygame.Surface((settings.ANT_RADIUS*2, settings.ANT_RADIUS*2))
    self.draw()
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.pos = self.world.nest.pos
    self.rect.center = self.pos
    self.in_nest = True
    self.image.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
    self.target = False

def update(self):
    if self.in_nest:
        self.try_leave_nest()
    else:
        if self.target != False:
            self.move_to_food()
        else:
            self.target = self.find_food()

def draw(self):
    pygame.draw.circle(self.image, settings.ANT_COLOUR,
                       (settings.ANT_RADIUS, settings.ANT_RADIUS), settings.ANT_RADIUS)

def move_to_food(self):
    self.direction = vec(self.target.pos-self.pos).normalize()
    self.pos += self.direction
    self.rect.center = self.pos
    print(self.pos)

def find_food(self):
    self.closest = settings.WINDOW_WIDTH
    self.closest_food = False
    for food in self.world.food:
        if not food.taken:
            self.distance = self.pos.distance_to(food.pos)
            if self.distance <= self.closest:
                self.closest = self.distance
                self.closest_food = food
    self.closest_food.taken = True
    return self.closest_food

def try_leave_nest(self):
    leave_chance = settings.ANT_LEAVE_CHANCE
    leave_num = random.random()
    if leave_num < leave_chance:
        self.in_nest = False
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Remove everything that's not needed to reproduce the problem, but make sure that the program is still runnable.

Comment: Sorry first post and wasn't entirely sure what was causing the issue. Will keep this in mind on future posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.pos = self.world.nest.pos`

Copies a reference to the position object, not the object itself!

`self.pos += self.direction`

Modifies the object inplace, meaning `self.world.nest.pos` is modified, too.

Comment: Exactly. It should be `self.pos = vec(self.world.nest.pos)` to actually create a new `Vector2`.

Comment: Thanks for that. May have over complicated this code but wanted to so I would run into things like this and know whats going on and how to fix them.